# How to merge multi json objects in c++ using nlhoman json

Tags: c++, json, merge

I have below code:

```
json obj1 = {
{ 1,  "a" }, { 2, "b" }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    json obj2 = {
       {  3+i, "c" }
    };
    std::cout << "obj2 = " << obj2 << std::endl;
    obj1.merge_patch(obj2);
    std::cout << "obj1 merg =  " << obj1 << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "obj1 =  " << obj1 << std::endl;
```

Here the results:

```
obj2 = [[3,"c"]]
obj1 merg =  [[3,"c"]]
obj2 = [[4,"c"]]
obj1 merg =  [[4,"c"]]
obj1 =  [[4,"c"]]
```

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Erc4q6dhx)

How do you interpret the results ? and how i can obtain {1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, "c"} ?

Comment: It looks like `obj2` is not actually an object, since it is printing as an array of arrays. That would screw up any merge patches you intend to do

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. When you say you want `{1, "a", ...}`, did you mean `[1, "a", ...]`? One is an object, the other is an array.

Comment: It looks like merge patches do not actually support merging arrays, they can only replace arrays.

Comment: I want obtain {1, "a", 2, ...} and not [1, "a", ...]

Comment: That is impossible. Objects contain key:value pairs, not separate elements. Did you mean `{"1": "a", "2": "b", ...}` ?

Comment: I have an error when i write json obj1 = {{"1": "a"}} through visual studio

Comment: Because that is JSON notation, not C++. I am asking you about the shape of the resulting JSON structure. Do you want an object or an array?

Comment: Note that in a good JSon key of the object must be a string. You are trying to create key from type `int` so library assumes list not a pair of key values of JSon object.

Comment: After ensuring that keys are a strings, code immediately seems to work similar to your requirement: https://godbolt.org/z/Tv48f5dYb

Comment: @Botje thank you for the explication, can i have the answers in case of  array and another for object please

Comment: @SADL note that JSON is acronym for "Java Script Object Notation" so grammar of JSON is grammar of Java Script and it doesn't cooperate with C++ grammar, so some compromises must be taken. You can feed JSON to C++ as a string and then parse it, or you have to use C++ notation which library will adopt to proper JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "objects" are all missing the following heuristic of the nlohmann::json constructor:

> In case type_deduction is true (default), the type of the JSON value to be created is deducted from the initializer list init according to the following rules:

> - If the list is empty, an empty JSON object value {} is created.
> - If the list consists of pairs **whose first element is a string**, a JSON object value is created where the first elements of the pairs are treated as keys and the second elements are as values.
> - In all other cases, an array is created.

You can solve it by explicitly requesting an object:

```
json obj1 = json::object({{ 1,  "a" }, { 2, "b" }});
```